# What percentage of the bits used for data in a 32kB (32,768 byte) direct-mapped write-back cache with a 64 byte cache line?

Tags: caching, mips

Encountered this problem and the solution said
"32 bit address bits, 64 byte line means we have 6 bits for the word address in the line that aren't in the tag, 32,768 bytes in the cache at 64 byte lines is 512 total lines, which means we have 12 bits of address for the cache index, write back means we need a dirty bit, and we always need a valid bit. So each line has 64*8=512 data bits, 32-6- 12=14 tag bits, and 2 flag bits: data/total bits = 512/(512+14+2)=512/528."

When I tried to solve the problem I got 32kB/64byte=512 lines in total, i.e. 2^9=512. In addition, a 64 byte cache line size, 1 word=4 bytes, is 64/4=16 words per line i.e. 2^4. 
To my understanding the total amount of bits in a cache is given by total amount of entries/lines in the caches*(tag address + data)-> 2^9*((32-9-4+2)+16*32). Thus, the amount of data bits per cache line is 512 (16 words *32 bits per word), and the tag is 32-9-4+2=21 (the 9 is the cache index for direct mapped cache, the 4 is to address each word and the 2 is the valid bit and dirty bit) 
Effectively, the answer should be 512/533 and not 512/528.

Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

512 lines = 9 bits not 12 as they claim, so you are right on this point.

However, they are right that 64 byte lines gives 6 bits for the block offset — though it is a byte offset, not word as they say.

So, 32-6-9=17 tag bits, then plus the 2 for dirty & valid.

FYI, there's nothing in the above problem that indicates a conversion from bytes to words.  While it is true that there will be 16 x 32-bit words per line (i.e. 64 bytes per line) it is irrelevant: we should presume that the 32-bit address is a byte address unless otherwise stated.  (It would be unusual to state cache size in bytes for a word (not byte) addressable machine; it would also be unusual for a 32-bit machine to be word addressable — some teaching architectures like LC-3 are word addressable, however, they are 16-bits; other word addressable machines have odd sizes like 12 or 18 or 36 bit words — though those pre-date caches!)

Comment: Thank you! So the 6 bits is to be able to address each byte in the cache line? I.e. 64 byte line size->2^6 . Then the formulation should rather be "...6 bits are needed for the byte-address in the line..."? 

The answer should then be 512/(512+(32-9-6+2))->512/ 531. Correct?

Comment: Yes.  Sometimes those 6 bits are referred to as the block offset.